# Robocopy copy: report: Dirs, Files, and Bytes are all 0 for Extras, but Times is 0:00:01. Why?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I copied a few files with `robocopy` on Windows 10. In the final report, `Dirs`, `Files`, and `Bytes` are all `0` for `Extras`, however `Times` is `0:00:01` for `Extras`. How is that possible?

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         4         3         1         0         0         0
   Files :        91        91         0         0         0         0
   Bytes : 218.184 g 218.184 g         0         0         0         0
   Times :   1:00:24   1:00:23                       0:00:00   0:00:01


   Speed :            64660373 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            3699.896 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Tuesday, January 9, 2024 10:18:03 AM
```

I used this command to copy  the files:

```
robocopy /e source_folder destination_folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No actions were performed on "Extra" files (files in destination, but not in source); They are simply reported in the program output log. Even though there were no extras in that run, robocopy still takes a measurable amount of time to look for them (probably rounded up to 01 seconds in your example).

If you include the switch `/XX`, it will skip checking for extra files